# PHP Remove a single letter from a long string only once?

Tags: php, string

I need to remove a single character from a string, eg in the text block below I would need to be able to remove ONE of the j's.

djriojnrwadoiaushd

leaving:

driojnrwadoiaushd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*You can also use str_relpace with the $count parameter:
    $str = 'djriojnrwadoiaushd';
    echo str_replace('j', '', $str, 1);*

Ups, sorry.. my bad.

---

Here is a real way:

```
$str = 'djriojnrwadoiaushd';
$pos = strpos( $str, 'j' );
if( $pos !== FALSE )
{
    echo substr_replace( $str, '', $pos, 1 );
}
```

Comment: The last argument doesnt limit the number of replacements, it counts them.

Answer (score 3):

Just use substrings:

```
<?php

$str = 'djriojnrwadoiaushd';
$remove = 'j';

$index = strpos($str, $remove);
if ($index !== false)
    $str = substr($str, 0, $index) . substr($str, $index + 1);

echo $str;

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Stand back - I know regular expressions;

```
$newString = preg_replace("/".preg_quote($stringToReplace)."/", '', $inputString, 1);
```

Comment: You should maybe consider calling preg_quote() on $stringToReplace otherwise you might get odd things happening, e.g. if $stringToReplace was .*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$needle = 'j';
if (($pos = strpos($str, $needle) !== false) {
    $str = substr($str, 0, $pos) . substr($str, $pos+strlen($needle));
}
```

Comment: A combination of this with mishac's answer would be neat.

Answer (score 0):

[strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns the position of the first needle in the haystack, ie. the first j in your string. It's then quite simple to just remove that letter.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the fact that strings in PHP are arrays, and remove the element corresponding to the 'j':

```
$str[strpos($str, 'j')] = null;
```

Comment: Interesting approach.  If there is no j, however, this will probably try to remove the first letter.

Comment: When being printed it displays a character firefox doesn't recognize, but for my purpose it works.

Comment: Are you just overwriting the j with a null rather than removing it?  Sounds like you have to split the string and rejoin the beginning and the end leaving out the character you wish to remove.